# Show spinner loader on submit button in form with click

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to show spinner loader when I click on submit button but submit button is not working. Spinner loader appears for some time but submit button is not hitting the controller method. And if you have a better login approach, please guide me.

Here's my button code:

```
<form action="@Url.Action("ForgotPassword","Account")" method="post">
   <div class="form-row">
       <label class="form-side__form-group  form-group col-md-12">
           <input class="form-control" type="text" id="fname" name="email" placeholder="Email" value="@TempData[TempKeys.Email]">
       </label>
   </div>
   <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
       <button id="send-button" class="btn btn-primary form-side__btn" type="submit">Send 
           <div id="button-spinner" style="margin-left: 10px; width: 15px; height: 15px; display: none" class="spinner-border"></div>
       </button>
   </div>
   <div class="form-side__password mt_20">
       <h6>Already have an account? <a href="@Url.Action("Login", "Account")">Login</a></h6>
   </div>
   <p class="@TempData[TempKeys.ValidateClass]">@TempData[TempKeys.ValidateMessage]</p>
</form>
```

And here's my jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#send-button').click(function () {
        $('#send-button').attr('disabled', true);
        $('#button-spinner').show();
        setTimeout(function () {
          $('#button-spinner').hide();
        }, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Is there a form tag in your HTML?  Please edit your question and add your form tag so we can see its attributes.  Also, please add the signature of your controller method.

Comment: Yes i'm using Form tag with POST method. Submit button not hitting on controller method.

Comment: Also, it's illegal HTML to have a div tag inside a button tag.

Comment: I've edited the question.

Comment: Can you post your controller method header?

Answer (score 0):

Add one id to form and code of javascript

```
 <form id="formProcess" action="@Url.Action("ForgotPassword","Account")" method="post">

  $(document).ready(function () {
$('#send-button').click(function () {
    $('#send-button').attr('disabled', true);
    $('#button-spinner').show();
    setTimeout(function () {
      $('#button-spinner').hide();
    }, 2000);
$('#formProcess').submit();
});
 });
```